# How to delete (noisy and short) lines?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, line, noise

Using OpenCV with Python, I'm trying to find horizontal and vertical lines in my image.

This is my output :

vertical_lines

[image]

horizontal_lines

[image]

Well, I'm trying to detect only the long lines and delete the short (noisy) lines.

I hope that my output looks like this modified image:

Final_Horizontal_lines

[image]

I can provide you with my code if needed.

Comment: I used HoughlinesP (minLineLength ) but still nothing -_-

Comment: Yes, show your code. also show the input image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve that problem by using contours.

```
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for contour in contours:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    # if h<500: # check the length of verical lines 
    if w<500: # check the length of horizontal lines
        cv2.fillConvexPoly(gray,contour,0) #fill the contour with black color
```

[image]